# iOS 7 - CoreData Migration - Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm having a very curious problem performing a CoreData Migration.

Basically, I have 2 entities, where in one of them I add a property and in the other, I change a property type from NSString to NSArray(Transformable).
So far, so good, it works well, tests were made and the data integrity was intact after the migration.

The problem happens if I run the exact same code on Xcode 5 (I don't know if it's related to iOS SDK 7.0 or Xcode 5), but the migration runs and corrupts the data.

I ended up creating a simple project to demonstrate what's happening.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1393279/CoreDataMigration.zip

The steps to reproduce is:
- On Xcode 5 (iOS SDK 7.0), you can use the simulator -

1 - Open the project "BeforeMigration" and execute. See the logs and data created, no problem so far;

2 - Stop the project;

3 - Open the project "AfterMigration", build and run.

4 - See that the migration is executed, but the data gets corrupted:

> 2013-11-13 12:22:29.778 CoreDataMigration[7223:70b] CoreData: error:
>   exception during fetchRowForObjectID: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>   initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x43, 0x32, 0x0,
>   0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) with userInfo of (null) 2013-11-13
>   12:22:29.782 CoreDataMigration[7223:70b]**  Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '**
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x43, 0x32, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)'

AFAIK, incomprehensible archive means corrupted data on CoreData.

What's difficult to understand is that the same exact code worked before, so, if it's a logic problem, it should have happened on Xcode 4.5. I looked for CoreData Diffs but didn't find anything relevant.

If anyone have any idea of what could be the problem, I would appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, you changed a property to an NSArray? Core Data doesn't have an array type. How are you saving the data, and how are you migrating an NSString to an NSArray?

Comment: Sorry, I changed to a transformable

Comment: I found that the issue only happens if I call "backupSourceStoreAtURL". It seems that I can't rename the .sqlite file anymore. Not sure why.

Comment: What is the `backupSourceStoreAtURL` method? It's not part of Core Data, or of any API from Apple.

Comment: It's a custom method that creates a backup from my original store. Basically, I create a backup from my original store, then I remove the old .sqlite file and rename the new one to use the same name as the old, the backup file is restored in case something goes wrong with this. It seems that on previous SDK version I could rename the .sqlite file without any problems, and now I can't.

Comment: I can "fix" this by removing this backup method, and sending "destinationStoreURL" instead of "sourceStoreURL" at the end of progressivelyMigrateURL method, but I really would like to understand why I can't rename the .sqlite file anymore.

Comment: If I set the NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}, on both versions (after and before), it works. The problem is that I need to set it on the "before" project as well, and I only have control over the "after". Source: http://pablin.org/2013/05/24/problems-with-core-data-migration-manager-and-journal-mode-wal/

Comment: I've been playing around and i think it might 'just' be a bug. Did you report this to Apple?

Comment: No, I did ask for the iOS Developer Program tech support, but nothing so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 7, the default journaling mode of Core Data SQLite store has been changed to Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) to improve the reliability, performance, and concurrency.

The problem was that I wasn't moving the -wal file with the core data. One way to fix it  is to remove -wal using:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
```

Or moving the -wal with:

```
- (NSPersistentStore *)migratePersistentStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store toURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary *)options withType:(NSString *)storeType error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use moGenerator [link](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) and try these steps:

- use MOGen (or MOGenerator) to auto generate you core data model entity classes from the model with every build (use dedicated pre-build target for that);
- always enable model versioning when creating a new data model;
- when creating a new version of a data model:

  1. add new data model version - call it "new version";
     set its Core Data Model Identifier to next desired version (like: 1.1 or 2.0, etc.). This is logical developer friendly identifier of  the model version - it does not force Core Data to treat this version differently unless critical changes are made to it;
  2. rename what used to be current model version by appending its Version Identifier to the name. For example if it was "MyDataModel.xcdatamodel" that had its Version Identifier set to 1.1 - rename it into "MyDataModel_1.1.xcdatamodel";
  3. rename the newly added version into the simple model name, like "MyDataModel.xcdatamodel" and make it the Current Version. This way you always keep name of the current model version the same and your MOGen's activation/build scripts will not change (in case you do use MOGen - and you should);
  4. modify the current model as needed;
  5. depending on the scale of the changes made to the model, Core Data Lightweight Migration capabilities may handle it as is. If the changes are extansive you may need to define your own Mapping Model to help the Core Data to migrate an older data store into the latest version of the model;
  6. clean your Product;
  7. rebuild your Product;
  8. test it.

Best practices by Andrey Kornich